# How do eVisas increase tourism by 400%?

Tags: visas, india, factoids, statistics, e-visas

Today [I read in the news](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/E-visa-power-Tourism-shot-up-by-400-in-a-year-Rajnath/articleshow/46281239.cms) that eVisas have increased tourism for India by 400%. How do eVisas increase tourism so drastically? How is it different from a regular visa in terms of increasing tourism?

Comment: I couldn't find a tourism tag to add to the question. I did see specific tourism tags like medical tourism , ecotourism but no generic tourism tag. Lack of a tourism tag looks strange.

Comment: It'd be too generic - just about every question on here could be tagged with it.

Comment: Yeah true, did we have the tag before and [burninate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) the tag because it was too generic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The increase is in visas on arrival and not tourists

Assume India had 100 visitors earlier, of which 10 availed of visa on arrival. Now 50 of them avail of visa on arrival

http://qz.com/329397/no-tourists-arent-exactly-thronging-to-india-since-modi-launched-visa-on-arrival/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. The news article I saw is so misleading.

Comment: @Sri One must be careful of what is reported by Times of India `;)`, particularly their online version. I am an avid TOI reader and their online news has deteriorated to difficultly poor qualities.

Comment: +1 Worth adding that the actual increase in **visitors** in the same 2013-14 time period was just 6.8% - which is actually lower than the increase was in 2012-2013 (when it increased by 9%)

Answer (score 6):

eVisas are easier to obtain, thus encouraging more people to visit.  While for many who visit this forum, visas are but a minor nuisance, to many they are an obstacle, finding the form to fill out, going to get photos made, going to the bank for a bank money order ... easier to go somewhere else.

Though I find a 400% increase to be stretching it a bit for these reasons alone.  There would likely be additional reasons such as lower fees, higher approval rates, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that it make the visa process easier. I  was wondering how eVisa would increase tourism by 400%. I will reword the question a bit.

Comment: This 400% is probably because the visa process in India used to be a slow one with a lot of paperwork. Additionally, there were some rules that you have to apply for a visa from the country your citizenship is at. This prevented many people from coming to India "on their way".

Answer (score 5):

A comparison just for the sake of making an example would be online shopping vs conventional shopping. Which one is easier? Ordering a movie online and being able to watch it on spot without moving your lazy butt or going all the way to the store to get the DVD?

Same thing goes for visas. Most people when planning a vacation they put a list of places to choose from, then they start checking prices and other stuff and visa is indeed on top of that list. Being able to have the visa easily will be a big plus to that destination.

Other thing, online visas mean there is less auditing by humans, computers can do that stuff faster and in some cases it will be issued on-spot, and the faster the visa is granted, the more people will be putting that destination on the top of the list.